# Making method to give value of m or M based on position

Tags: java, methods

So i have to make a method that will return a value based on m or M in a string. so far i have this

```
public static int mIndex(String x) {
    if (x.indexOf('M') >= 0) {
        return x.indexOf('M');
    }
    if (x.indexOf('m') >= 0) {
        return x.indexOf('m');
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The problem is that it only returns M if it is first in the String. Is there anyway for it to detect m or M, and then give a value based on that?

Comment: Your question is confusing... elaborate more on what you want the program to accomplish. "The problem is that it only returns M if it is first in the String" how is this a bad thing?

Comment: do you want to get all the indexes of 'M' or 'm' ?

Comment: I would like the program to tell the position of m or M, whichever comes first.

Comment: For example if i had a string that was "kamdkMMM" the index would be 2, since it reaches the lowercase m first, then it would ignore the M after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something like that, a regular expression is your friend:

```
public static int mIndex(String x) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[mM]").matcher(x);
    if (m.find())
        return m.start();
    return -1;
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(mIndex("kamdkMMM"));
System.out.println(mIndex("KAMDKmmm"));
System.out.println(mIndex("Hello World"));
```

*Output*

```
2
2
-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String s = "MarshmallowmmMaM";
System.out.println("Index of 'M':");
int index = s.indexOf("M");
while (index >= 0) {
        System.out.println(index);
        index = s.indexOf("M", index + 1);
    }
System.out.println("Index of 'm':");
index = s.indexOf("m");
while (index >= 0) {
        System.out.println(index);
        index = s.indexOf("m", index + 1);
    }
```

**Output:**

> Index of 'M':
>   0
>   13
>   15
>
> Index of 'm':
>   5
>   11
>   12

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect the first position of each case for letter M. "upper&lower".

```
public class Main {
public static int M_POSITION = -1;
public static int m_POSITION = -1;
public static void mIndex(String x) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < x.length()) {
        if (x.charAt(i) == 'M') {
            if (M_POSITION == -1)
                M_POSITION = i;
        } else if (x.charAt(i) == 'm') {
            if (m_POSITION == -1)
                m_POSITION = i;
        }
        ++i;
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    mIndex("adsm");
    System.out.println(m_POSITION);
    System.out.println(M_POSITION);
}
}
```